# Single rotating dashed border around 3 consecutive <td>

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, jquery-selectors

I would like to create a rotating dashed border around a table row except for the first `<td>` when hovering over the corresponding button. I already tried to get it done by using background transition as shown here:

[Dashed border animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365839/dashed-border-animation-in-css3-animation)

The only problem is that the border will be obscured by the background color of the `<td>` with the class="boundary", so it goes behind it as shown here:

[border goes behind background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRQSl.jpg)

z-index does not work in this case.

I also tried this example without any success:

[Rotating dashed border by Sean Lynch](https://codepen.io/techniq/pen/gzyHI)

I ended up with but this:

[SVG line animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572865/how-to-animated-rounded-dashed-border)

I really don´t know how to adapt this to my code that you will find here:

[This is my code](https://codepen.io/Tissi_2/pen/VgrJGL)

Comment: Instead of using a table you may consider using rows of divs

Comment: Thanks for the answer but also with divs there is the problem with the obscured border.

Comment: for the contrast you may use `mix-blend-mode`. `difference` may be a choice

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pseudo element where you apply the dashed border animation

```css
.inner_wrap {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.boundary {
  width: 5%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: steelblue;
}

.occupied0 {
  background-color: #1b4d15;
  color: #fff;
}

.occupied1 {
  background-color: red;
  color: #FFF;
}

.short {
  width: 32%;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10%;
}

.long {
  width: 76%;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10%;
}

td.range_supervisor {
  background-color: #663300;
  width: 12%;
  padding: 35px;
  background-clip: content-box;
}

table {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: left;
  border: 0px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

table>tr>td {
  width: 25%;
}

tr:first-child td:first-child:before {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:20px;
    right:20px;
    height:60px;
      background: 
        linear-gradient(90deg, blue 50%, transparent 50%) 0 0, 
        linear-gradient(90deg, blue 50%, transparent 50%) 100% 100%, 
        linear-gradient(0deg, blue 50%, transparent 50%) 100% 0, 
        linear-gradient(0deg, blue 50%, transparent 50%) 0 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat-y;
  background-size: 16px 4px, 16px 4px, 4px 16px, 4px 16px;
  transition: background-position 2s;
}

tr:first-child:hover td:first-child:before{
    background-position: 200px 0, calc(100% - 200px) 100%, 100% 50px,0 calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<table class="inner_wrap">
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;">
      <button>RANGE 1</button>
    </td>
    <td class="boundary"></td>
    <td id="range1" class="short occupied0">
      AVAILABLE
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button>RANGE 2</button>
    </td>
    <td class="boundary"></td>
    <td id="range2" class="short occupied0">
      AVAILABLE
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button>RANGE 3</button>
    </td>
    <td class="boundary"></td>
    <td id="range3" class="short occupied0">
      AVAILABLE
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button>RANGE 4</button>
    </td>
    <td class="boundary"></td>
    <td id="range4" class="short occupied0">
      AVAILABLE
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="range_supervisor" rowspan="4">
      <button style="  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
   text-orientation: upright;">supervisor</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button>RANGE 5</button>
    </td>
    <td class="boundary"></td>
    <td id="range5" class="long occupied0">
      AVAILABLE
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button>RANGE 6</button>
    </td>
    <td class="boundary"></td>
    <td id="range6" class="long occupied0">
      AVAILABLE
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button>RANGE 7</button>
    </td>
    <td class="boundary"></td>
    <td id="range7" class="long occupied0">
      AVAILABLE
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button>RANGE 8</button>
    </td>
    <td class="boundary"></td>
    <td id="range8" class="long occupied0">
      AVAILABLE
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button>RANGE 9</button>
    </td>
    <td class="boundary"></td>
    <td id="range9" class="short occupied0">
      AVAILABLE
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button>RANGE 10</button>
    </td>
    <td class="boundary"></td>
    <td id="range10" class="short occupied0">
      AVAILABLE
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button>RANGE 11</button>
    </td>
    <td class="boundary"></td>
    <td id="range11" class="short occupied0">
      AVAILABLE
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button>RANGE 12</button>
    </td>
    <td class="boundary"></td>
    <td id="range12" class="short occupied0">
      AVAILABLE
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, that is almost that what I wanted. I will adjust the code so that the most left '<td>' will not be selected ( the border should start left of the button ) , the rotating animation will be infinite and border will only be visible when hovering over the corresponding button. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Tissi_2 in this case you simply need to add `position:relative` to the td so that the pseudo element will only be around it ... for the infinite animation simply use animation, let me know if you want me to edit the answer

Comment: I will try it on my own. If I am not able to solve it, I will get back.

Comment: Well, I updated the pen but it´s still not the result that I really want. I added a little bit of jquery in order to show you what it should look like. The problem is that the first column '<td>s' are being selected as well (the left border should be near to the button) and the dashed border is running in the background of the boundary-tds again. I am a little bit stuck how it should work with the pseudo-elements :-/