# How to animate U shaped dashed border?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-animations, border

I am trying to animate a U-shaped dashed border to make it move from left to right continuously.

Need help with code pls <3.

Here is the code.

```
.curved-dots-path {
  align-self: center;
  width: 70%;
  border: 5px dashed var(--org-primary-color);
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
  height: 25rem;
  margin-top: -30rem;
}
```

[image of U-shaped dashed border - animation to be moved from left to right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5wnl.png)

Comment: You can achieve that using svg. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39586306/13199446)

Comment: @la_petite_kozel thanks but its very complicated for me. Can please help with the code for it? I'll deeply appreciate it!

Comment: Posted a brief example with some explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Create SVG curved line, if you are not familiar with creating SVG's programmatically you can draw it in Illustrator, Inkscape or any other SVG editor and export it.

Add stroke-dasharray property to your SVG. `stroke-dasharray: 15, 10;` means each line is 15px width with 5px gap between. `stroke-dashoffset: 0` is starting position and `stroke-dashoffset: -25` in dash animation is how many pixels stroke should be moved, set it to sum of gap and stroke width (25px = 15 + 10) to avoid jumps.

```css
svg {
  stroke-dasharray: 15, 10;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: dash 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: -25;
  }
}

path {
  stroke: #000;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <path d="M50,50 Q100,100 150,50" />
</svg>
```

Update:

Here is a nice online [tool](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/) that allows you to customize SVG paths according to your preferences.